# How to create binary pandas dataframe by checking value is equal to mode or not

Tags: pandas, dataframe, masking

I want to create binary pandas dataframe from existing pandas dataframe. values of binary pandas dataframe will be 1 if its equal to mode otherwise it will be 0.

P.S. I have more than 100 columns so cant do manually for each columns.

Comment: `df.eq(df.mode().iloc[0]).astype(int)` ?

Comment: No problem , `df.mode()` returns more than 1 value unlike other aggregations so we should keep in mind to pick the first value(subjective)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df.eq(df.mode().iloc[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

using vectorization:

```
mode_condition = <your conditions>

df['newcol'] = np.where(mode_condition, 1, 0)
```